# Measuring tariff evasion before and after tariff cut

Tags: time-series, least-squares, case-control-study

I have data on tariff rates and a proxy for tariff evasion (that is common in the literature). The data spans a couple of years before the country I'm studying implements a tariff reform and lowers its tariffs. The data also spans many years after the implementation of this tariff reform. Now I'm looking for a suitable way of analyzing the effect this tariff reduction has had on evasion (given it's a good proxy). The hypothesis, perhaps obviously, is that a lowering of the tariff rate will lead to a decrease in evasion. I've read about the difference-in-difference method but here I don't have a "control group". I'm quite a new practitioner to econometrics so any suggestions will do. I'm thinking that even though the simple set up (sorry for the sloppy notation):  evasion(i) = intercept + B1(tariff(i)) + error(i) were to be run on some year(s) before and after the tariff reform and a reduced effect on tariff is found, there are possibly a number of things that could have influenced this change in evasion other than the tariff reduction. What are the the problems and possibilities with this data-set?  Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Thanks! /Oscar

Comment: You could look at tariff lines where there is no tariff reduction, or at other countries which do not change their tariffs in the same period, as your comparator.  Personally I suspect trade mirror statistics (which I assume you are using) may be a fairly weak proxy for tariff evasion: the world runs a trade deficit in goods with itself, while the EU (which does not have internal tariffs) runs a trade surplus in goods with itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simplified difference-in-difference approach here would assume that the average evasion is constant over time and only changes as a result of the reform. Hence, the simplest calculation would subtract average evasion before the reform from average evasion after the reform. A more complicated model would regress the evasion level at time t on a bunch of predictors at time t, plus an indicator for whether the reform had happened yet. Here, you are assuming that all the slopes that describe evasion are the same before and after reform; the only thing that changes is the level of reform conditional on the predictors.

When using panel data, you need to worry about serial correlation. See this paper, for example:
Bertrand, Marianne, Ester Duflo, and Sendhil Mullainathan. 2004. "How Much Should We Trust Differences-in-Differences Estimates?" Quarterly Journal of Economics. 119(1): 249--275. [[prepub version](http://econ-www.mit.edu/files/750)]